# Capture Screen memory to a bitmap (visual c++ 6.0)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am using visual c++ 6.0 and need to capture the image on the screen to memory.  How do I do this?  thx

Comment: Step 1 - install Visual Studio 2010 C++ Express and uninstall VC6. [Are you really stuck with VC6?]  The APIs you use will not depend on the IDE but your life will be a lot easier with a newer one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Get the DC for the screen with `GetDC(NULL)`
- Create a memory DC with `CreateCompatibleDC`.
- Create a bitmap compatible with the screen DC and the same size as the screen.
- Select the bitmap into the memory DC.
- BitBlt from the screen DC to the memory DC.
- Deselect the bitmap from the memory DC.
- Use `GetBitmapBits` to copy the bitmap into memory.